# Combining ... vs ... combined

Tags: meaning

1. Combining (1) and (2) implies (3).
2. (1) and (2) combined imply (3).

I am writing a paper in maths, and (1), (2), and (3) are all mathematical expressions. A co-author wrote like Number 1 but I thought it was weird so I changed it to Number 2, but I'm not really sure if Number 1 is incorrect. I feel like Number 1 is saying the act of combining (1) and (2) is implying something, not the expressions (1) and (2). But at the same time I found some papers where they wrote like Number 1 so I'm quite confused.

So are Number 1 and Number 2 the same? If so, which is preferable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the contexts of a maths paper, both are clear and denote

> ((1) and (2)) => (3).

However, I agree that the first sentence is slightly strange: how can the act of combination itself imply the the veracity of a mathematical proposition? I would instead write

> Combining (1) and (2) yields (3).

When I write formal mathematics, I use *yield* to denote the result of a process (e.g. the process of combining expressions or applying syllogisms) and reserve *imply* for logical consequence. Of course, this is a very technical point. In less formal situations, either word can be used more generally.

Comment: Mathematician here. This doesn't address the main question but may help you actually wrote your paper, so I'll add to this accepted answer:  I suggest writing, "Together, (1) and (2) imply (3)."